# Oracle counting distinct rows using two columns merged as one

Tags: oracle, distinct

I have one table where each row has three columns. The first two columns are a prefix and a value. The third column is what I'm trying to get a distinct count for columns one/two.

Basically I'm trying to get to this.

| Account | Totals |
| --- | --- |
| prefix & value1 | 101 |
| prefix & value2 | 102 |
| prefix & value3 | 103 |

I've tried a lot of different versions but I'm basically noodling around this.

```
select prefix||value as Account, count(distinct thirdcolumn) as Totals from Transactions
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT
 prefix||value Account,
 count(distinct thirdcolumn) Totals
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY prefix, value
```

The `count(distinct thirdcolumn)` says you want a count of the distinct values in the third column. The `GROUP BY prefix, value` says you want a row returned for each unique prefix/value combination and that the `count` applies to that combination.

Note that "thirdcolumn" is a placeholder for the name of your third column, not a magic keyword, since I didn't see the actual name in the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of rows for each `prefix`/`value` pair then you can use:

```sql
SELECT prefix || value AS account,
       COUNT(*) AS totals
FROM   Transactions
GROUP BY prefix, value
```

You do not want to count the `DISTINCT` values for `prefix`/`value` as if you `GROUP BY` those values then different values for the pairs will be in different groups so the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` `prefix`/`value` pairs would always be one.